# How to do HTTP GET with netcat?

Tags: http, netcat

I am trying to use `netcat` to submit an `HTTP GET` request. But it gives me the 505 error.

Does anybody know what is wrong with my use of `netcat`?
Thanks.

---

```
$ cat main.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

netcat -v httpbin.org 80 <<EOF
GET /get HTTP/1.1

EOF

$ ./main.sh
httpbin.org [23.23.171.5] 80 (http) open
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Connection: close
Server: Cowboy
Date: Fri, 09 Feb 2018 00:26:37 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use CRLF line endings, and you must include a Host header.

```
~$ printf 'GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:httpbin.org\r\n\r\n' | nc -v httpbin.org 80 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[…]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more readable solution.

```
$ sed 's/$/\r/g' <<EOF | netcat -v httpbin.org 80
GET /get HTTP/1.1
Host:httpbin.org

EOF
```